# Undetermined Coefficient method and variation parameter method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuK8d.png)

Can someone tell me why the undetermined Coefficient method failed? I got y_p=(e^2z)/8 when using undetermined Coefficient method but when using variation parameter y_p is different

Edit:

DEQ is $(1+2x)^2y′′−6(1+2x)y′+16y=8(1+2x)^2 $

Comment: yes, sorry about that

Comment: What was your approach?

Comment: The solution is there in the png i attatched, the particular solution is found using variation parameter method but when i tried to find the particular solution using undetermined coefficient method the solution wasnt matching with the one  found using variation parameter. I have took  y=A*e^(-2z)  as the trial solution and got  y_p=(e^(2z))/8 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The particular solution you got using undetermined coefficients is already accounted for in the characteristic solution,

$$y_c=C_1e^{2z}+C_2ze^{2z}$$

For the ansatz, instead of $ae^{2z}$ (which seems to be what you did; I don't think your image shows that process anywhere), try $y_p=az^2e^{2z}$. Then

$${y_p}'=2aze^{2z}(1+z)\\
{y_p}''=2ae^{2z}(1+4z+2z^2)$$

Substituting this into the left side of $(D^2-4D+4)y=2e^{2z}$ gives

$$2ae^{2z}(1+4z+2z^2)-4(2aze^{2z})(1+z)+4az^2e^{2z}=2e^{2z}\\\implies 2a=2 \\\implies a=1\\\implies y_p=z^2e^{2z}$$

which agrees with the particular solution you found using variation of parameters.

Comment: omg im so dumb.....
i forgot a minus sign somewhere and got different particular solution when doing  undetermined coefficients.
sorry for wasting your time and thank you

Answer (score 1):

$$(1+2x)^2y′′−6(1+2x)y′+16y=8(1+2x)^2$$
$$u^2y′′−3uy′+4y=2u^2$$
Where $u=2x+1$. Now substitute $u=e^t$:
$$y′′−4y′+4y=2e^{2t}$$
$$(ye^{-2t})''=2$$
$$ye^{-2t}=t^2+c_1t+c_2$$
$$y(t)=e^{2t}(t^2+c_1t+c_2)$$
$$y(u)=u^2(\ln^2 u+c_1 \ln u+c_2)$$
$$y(x)=(2x+1)^2(\ln^2 |2x+1|+c_1 \ln |2x+1|+c_2)$$